# Raspberry pi mass storage

Tags: raspbian

I have followed this link [Unable to configure a Raspberry Pi Zero as a USB Mass Storage Device using g_mass_storage](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63914/unable-to-configure-a-raspberry-pi-zero-as-a-usb-mass-storage-device-using-g-mas)
for USB mass storage everything is working for me but it is not detecting in raspberry pi?

Comment: Why would you follow an (old) link to an unresolved problem and expect it to work?

Comment: yes it is working